# IIS intermittently redirect to wrong URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I am running IIS 8 and I setup a quick URL redirect from a virtual folder. The url resembles something like `home.cginet/applicaton/` and redirects to `home.cginet/applicaton/tools/`.

What happens randomly is when refreshing my page at the url `home.cginet/applicaton/` sometimes it will come back with `home.cginet/applicaton/tools/tools/tools/`. In order to fix this I have to refresh 3-4 times for the page to kick in.

Just wondering is anyone has seen this type of behavior with their site?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/Directory/staff/" exactDestination="false" childOnly="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post your rewrite code?

Comment: Update the post to add the code. The Directory folder is virtual if that matters.